# MySQL if updated older than 5 minutes and some other where clause

Tags: mysql

i have a big database table with few items that updated every seconds.

I want to show every item, that has percentage over 90% after 5 minutes on the live site and not directly.

This is the current Query (it works, but not with the 5min delay for items over 90% percentage of the old price to the new price

```
SELECT name, price, pricebefore, link, imagelink, updated, site, siteid 
FROM items 
WHERE (case when pricebefore3 is NULL then pricebefore else pricebefore3*1.5 end) >= pricebefore 
AND price < pricebefore 
AND isbn != -1 
AND (100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > ".$percentage." 
AND link LIKE '%".$merchant."%' 
ORDER BY updated DESC 
LIMIT ".$perPage." 
OFFSET ".$site;
```

Can someone help me?

I need something like that query but every item over 90% of price to pricebefore than i need a 5 minutes delay

Updated is a timestamp with on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and Standard CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Yeah but the Query is in the Quotes as you can see

Comment: Show: table's DDL, some data (example), example conditions (the values of the variables inserted into your query) and desired result for this data and conditions.

Comment: *a big database table with few items that updated every seconds* Does this means: there is many records, the most part of them is not altered at all, only a few records are updated, and none new records are inserted (?).

Comment: If a record is "updated every seconds", then where does all previous prices in a range of last 5 minutes must be taken from? And what if a price history is: 100% now, 99% at 5 minutes before, but 80% at 3 minutes before - does such record must be selected?

Comment: There much items yes, but that is not really of interest here?
I just need the query, to get items with more than 90% of price to pricebefore must be 5 minutes old on updated

Not every item get updates all the time. Only if a price is changed on the market. So if there is changed a price, it will hold for hours.

Comment: *So if there is changed a price, it will hold for hours.* This means nothing. In theory nothing prevents a price to be changed 10 times within 5 minutes. Or there is a constraint which prevents this?

Answer (score -1):

> I just need the query, to get items with more than 90% of price to pricebefore must be 5 minutes old on updated

```
SELECT *
FROM sourcetable
WHERE price/pricebefore <= (90 / 100)
  AND updatedAt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
-- AND another conditions if needed
-- ORDER BY, LIMIT, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! But with that i have the problem that EVERY item (also under 90%) has the 5 minutes interval.

Only if its over 90% than it must be older than 5 Minutes, not for everything :/ That is what my problem ist :D

So with that query everything has 5 minutes old

Comment: @txn That is why I have asked you for source data structure and complete data example to be inserted into your question.

Comment: What? As i told, ONLY if 90% over, that 90% items must have a 5 minutes delay, not everything. Sorry if you understand it wrong. Everything under 90% dont have a Interval (delay)

Comment: So the where if 90% or over must be combined with the interval of 5 minutes, than its working. But everything under 90% dont need the 5 minutes interval